# appendChild() вставка элемента в цикле

Tags: javascript

В цикле 5 раз вставляю созданный элемент. Элемент **H1** вставляется только один раз. В чем причина, подскажите. Спасибо.

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="box1"></div>
</body>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

***js/script.js***

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

 let box1 = document.querySelector('.box1');
 let h1 = document.createElement('H1');

 h1.innerHTML = 'Hello World!';

 for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
  box1.appendChild(h1);
 }

});
```

Comment: Уважаемый Grundy, название моего вопроса /appendChild() вставка элемента в цикле/ не является дубликатом. Он просто и четко подчеркивает проблему. Вы пытаетесь к свому ответу на вопрос /Как использовать (запускать) class в цикле/ привлечь лишнее внимание. Я так думаю.

Comment: Мой ответ отвечает на твой вопрос: _в чем причина_. И в принципе решение тоже описано.

Comment: Что бы найти Ваш ответ, должны быть ключевые слова в вопросе, где Ваш ответ. /Как использовать (запускать) class в цикле/ Где здесь можно найти? Обычный пиар Вашего ответа, не более.

Comment: который, тем не менее, отвечает на твой вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внутрь цикла создание элемента внесите.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

 let box1 = document.querySelector('.box1');

 for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
  let h1 = document.createElement('H1');    
  h1.innerHTML = 'Hello World!';

  box1.appendChild(h1);
 }

});
```

Comment: Уважаемый Suvitruf! Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: @Anton да не за что, собственно (:

Comment: Уважаемый Suvitruf! В двух слова, почему нужно именно в цикле создавать элемент, а не один раз создать переменную и добавлять переменную в цикле?

Comment: @Anton https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild "Если элемент уже существует он удаляется из текущего родителя и вставляется заново".